# Trouble navigating nested div with BeautifulSoup/ETree despite correct XPath

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I'm looking to extract the fields under the summary on [this](https://disclosures.ifc.org/project-detail/AS/604080/india-climate-smart-cities-ppp-program) link. I'm able to extract the field names (Project Number, Primary Business Area, Disclosure Date etc.) pretty easily using Selenium and BeautifulSoup/ETree.

```
driver.get('https://disclosures.ifc.org/project-detail/AS/604080/india-climate-smart-cities-ppp-program')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
fields = [x.text for x in dom.xpath('//div[@class=\'esrs-name\']')]
```

However I'm unable to use the `esrs-value` class to do the same for the values of the fields.

I've tried the following:

```
values = [x.text for x in dom.xpath('//div[@class=\'esrs-name\']')]
```

which only results in *(Project budget includes all project-funded activities)*. I noticed the divs are not structured the same for the multiple rows, and the div containing *(Project budget includes all project-funded activities)* seems to be higher than the others, but even

```
values = [x.text for x in dom.xpath('//div[@class=\'col-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4\']/div[not(@class)]/div[@class=\'esrs-value\']')]
```

results in `[]`.

I've tried using regular BeautifulSoup:

```
result = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"esrs-value"})
for res in result:
    print(res.text)
```

which also just returns *(Project budget includes all project-funded activities)*.

On using inspect on Chrome, I'm able to identify all 12 instances of the div class `esrs-value`, using `//div[@class='esrs-value']` so I'm not sure what's happening at all, because it only seems to be identifying one instance of `esrs-value`.

Edit:

Given the discrepancy in the results in the first answer, I thought I'd also give it a go on Replit (using only bs4) and saw the same result.

[image]

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to make a list composed of the text values in all of the `div` tags with the class `esrs-value`?

Comment: @Übermensch apologies for the delayed response. and yes, I need the summary fields and their values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting page you have here...

First, the relatively simple part - getting the data. The IFC has an API which returns a nice and clean json with all the data, without the need for selenium of beautifulsoup:

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('https://disclosuresservice.ifc.org/api/ProjectAccess/AdvisoryProject?projectId=604080')
#note: you can get the url of the api from the network tab from the developer view in the browser
data = req.json()
```

And that's it. Now you have the data which you can access, for example, like this:

```
data['ProjectOverView']['Project_Description']
```

outputs:

```
'IFC has entered ... sites in Gujarat.'
```

Or:

```
data['Status']
```

Output:

```
'Active'
```

etc.

The problem that comes up is the existence of inconsisitencies between the information on the landing page and in the json. I believe that a script populates the landing page table with "pending" and the like in places where it shouldn't. It may be that I misunderstand IFC terminology, but it's also possible that there are errors in that script. For example, for `IFC Approval Date`, the landing page shows `IFC Approval Date Pending`. On the other hand:

```
data['ApprovalDate']
```

returns

```
'2020-03-16T00:00:00'
```

Similarly, `Project Estimated Start Date` shows `Estimated Start Date Pending` but

```
data['EstimatedStartDate']
```

returns:

```
'2019-11-01T00:00:00'
```

Can't explain these things...

Comment: Oh that's amazing, thank you. Is there a way to extract the link from the networks tab automatically using selenium? I need to do this for a bunch of these projects..

Comment: @ashah There may be a way to do that (I'm not a selenium expert, I'm afraid), but in any case you should post it as a separate question, per SO policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate up the DOM tree via the `bs4.parent` attribute, and then search for the `esrs-value`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
dom = soup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = [{'name':i.text, 'value':i.parent.select_one('div.esrs-value').get_text(strip=1)} 
            for i in dom.select('div.esrs-name')]
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Project Number', 'value': '604080'}, {'name': 'Primary Business Area', 'value': 'Transaction Advisory'}, {'name': 'Disclosure Date', 'value': 'Mar 31, 2023'}, {'name': 'Country ', 'value': 'India'}, {'name': 'Region', 'value': 'South Asia'}, {'name': 'IFC Approval Date', 'value': 'IFC Approval Date Pending'}, {'name': 'Status', 'value': 'Active'}, {'name': 'Estimated Total Budget', 'value': 'Estimated Total Budget Pending'}, {'name': 'Last Updated Date', 'value': ''}, {'name': 'Project Estimated Start Date', 'value': 'Estimated Start Date Pending'}, {'name': 'Project Estimated End Date', 'value': 'Project Estimated End Date Pending'}, {'name': ' Project Description ', 'value': 'IFC has entered into Memorandum of Understanding (MoUs) with i) Kerala Infrastructure Investment Fund Board (KIFB); ii) PPP Department, Government of Goa; and iii) Gujarat Power Corporation Limited (GPCL). \n  \n  IFC will support KIFB and the Government of Goa in identification and screening of Public-Private Partnership (PPP) projects across infrastructure sectors and undertake pre-feasibility assessments of select projects. \n  \n  IFC will also support GPCL to conduct a pre-feasibility assessment for a potential pilot project to produce clean hydrogen-based renewable energy at one of GPCL’s sites in Gujarat.'}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately with the code I run into an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'". On removing the .get_text() I get a dictionary with all values as None, except for the "Estimated Total Budget" key which gives me the entire div tag with "Project budget includes all project-funded activities".

Comment: I'm still confused as to why I'm unable to reproduce this - I tried a couple variants and logically the code seems just fine. Are you able to reproduce the errors in the original post?

Comment: @ashah Strangely it runs just fine on my end: I am using ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71 on a Mac. Can you run either `document.querySelector('div.esrs-name')` in your browser dev console or `dom.select('div.esrs-name')` and see what containers are being returned? It is possible the site is rendering the page with different classnames for the target elements in your Chrome window.

Comment: On running `dom.select('div.esrs-name')` I get the div tags with the field names (project number/business area etc). On the dev console I get Project Number - interestingly on trying `document.querySelector('div.esrs-value')` I get 604080 as well -- but on printing `dom.select('div.esrs-value')` I only get the tag with the "Project budget.." line -- the same way as the last paragraph in the original post. This is driving my crazy! I'm using ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 on Mac.

Comment: @ashah Can you run `results = [{'name':i.text, 'value':i.parent} for i in dom.select('div.esrs-name')]` and see what is associated with `value`?

Comment: For the `value`, I get the div tag with the `esrs-name`. Which definitely seems entirely wrong, but I'm seeing this even on Replit. Edited post with output. `next_sibling` instead of `parent` returns in all `None`s except for the "project budget.."